# Error of "non-unique values when setting 'row.names'", after setting explicit unique row names

Tags: r, plm, r-rownames

here is a weird one:

I am working on the following data frame:

`str(ccomb)`

```
'data.frame':   358 obs. of  36 variables:
 $ Country.Name                                             : chr  "Albania" "Albania" "Albania" ...
 $ Donor                                                    : chr  "EU Institutions" "EU Institutions" ...
 $ Aid.type                                                 : chr  "ODA: Total Net" "ODA: Total Net" ...
 $ Amount.type                                              : chr  "Constant Prices" "Constant Prices" ...
 $ year                                                     : num  2002 2003 2004  ...
 $ Unit                                                     : chr  "US Dollar" "US Dollar" "US Dollar" ...
 $ PowerCode                                                : chr  "Millions" "Millions" "Millions" ...
 $ Reference.Period                                         : int  2020 2020 2020  ...
 $ Total_Net_ODA                                            : num  48.3 43.6 50.8 ...
 $ geo                                                      : chr  "EU27_2020" "EU27_2020" "EU27_2020" ...
 $ EU_Exp                                                   : num  1166 1281 1376  ...
 $ EU_Imp                                                   : num  355 396 416 ...
 $ Control_of_Corruption                                    : num  -0.854 -0.724 -0.813  ...
 $ Government_Effectiveness                                 : num  -0.569 -0.409 -0.705  ...
 $ Political_Stability_and_Absence_of_Violence_and_Terrorism: num  -0.31 -0.427 -0.505  ...
 $ Regulatory_Quality                                       : num  -0.4902 -0.1875 -0.4007 ...
 $ Rule_of_Law                                              : num  -0.716 -0.701 -0.764  ...
 $ Voice_and_Accountability                                 : num  0.07031 0.00724 0.00367  ...
 $ pop                                                      : num  3.04 3.03 3.01 2.99 2.97 ...
 $ GDPpC                                                    : num  2381 2522 2676 2851 3045 ...
 $ aNNI                                                     : num  6.66 7.06 7.33 7.85 8.14 ...
 $ openness                                                 : num  67 67 70.9 74.3 83.2 ...
 $ import                                                   : num  46.2 44.8 47.9 ...
 $ export                                                   : num  20.8 22.2 23 ...
 $ infmort                                                  : num  20.4 19.1 17.8 ...
 $ unemploy                                                 : num  17 16.3 16 15.6 16 ...
 $ v2x_polyarchy                                            : num  0.491 0.485 0.508 ...
 $ v2x_libdem                                               : num  0.398 0.4 0.416 0.436  ...
 $ v2x_partipdem                                            : num  0.318 0.322 0.341 ...
 $ v2x_delibdem                                             : num  0.383 0.382 0.422 ...
 $ v2x_egaldem                                              : num  0.355 0.353 0.361 ...
 $ ref_UNHCR_EU                                             : int  3851 3720 5385  ...
 $ ref_asyl_seekers_EU                                      : int  667 504 543 ...
 $ refugees_EU                                              : int  4518 4224 5928 ...
 $ Governance                                               : num  -2.87 -2.44 -3.18 ...
 $ region                                                   : chr  "Western Balkan" "Western Balkan" ...
```

When using plm() on this data, there are several issues, resulting in the error messages:
First, the error message occurs:

> Error in plm(Total_Net_ODA ~ logpop, logGDPpC, openness, import, export,  :
> arguments 'restrict.matrix' and 'restrict.rhs' cannot yet be used for single equations

When resolving this by setting restrict.matrix = NULL and restrict.rhs = NULL, it cannot find most of the variables anymore.
So, I used pdata.frame() to deal with this. It actually works, but causes another problem.
I used the following code for the transformation:

```
ccomb <- comb
str(ccomb)
rowvec <- c(1:358)
make.unique(.rowNamesDF(ccomb, make.names = TRUE) <- as.character(rowvec))
unique(rownames(ccomb))
duplicated(rownames(ccomb))
ccomb <- pdata.frame(comb, index=c("Country.Name", "year"), row.names = FALSE)
modE<-plm(Total_Net_ODA ~ openness, import, export, index=c("Country.Name", "year"),data = ccomb, model="within")
```

So, the code results in this error message:

> Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) :
> duplicate 'row.names' not allowed
> In addition: Warning message:
> non-unique values when setting 'row.names': ‘19’, ‘21’, ‘22’, ‘23’, ‘24’, ‘25’, ‘26’, ‘27’, ‘28’, ‘29’, ‘30’, ‘31’, ‘32’, ‘33’, ‘34’, ‘35’, ‘36’, ‘37’, ‘38’, ‘39’, ‘40’, ‘41’, ‘42’, ‘43’, ‘44’, ‘45’, ‘46’, ‘47’, ‘48’, ‘49’, ‘50’, ‘51’, ‘52’, ‘53’, ‘54’, ‘55’, ‘56’, ‘58’, ‘59’, ‘60’, ‘61’, ‘62’, ‘63’, ‘64’, ‘65’, ‘66’, ‘67’, ‘68’, ‘69’, ‘71’, ‘73’, ‘76’, ‘78’

Which  is weird, as the code above explicitly cancels out any nun-unique row names and the `duplicated(rownames(ccomb))` line explicitly states FALSE to every row.

I hope that this information is sufficient. If not, please let me know.

Here is my session info, in case that helps:

```
─ Session info ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 setting  value
 version  R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
 os       Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)
 system   x86_64, mingw32
 ui       RStudio
 language (EN)
 collate  German_Germany.utf8
 ctype    German_Germany.utf8
 tz       Europe/Berlin
 date     2023-02-23
 rstudio  2022.12.0+353 Elsbeth Geranium (desktop)
 pandoc   2.19.2 @ C:/Program Files/RStudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/bin/tools/ (via rmarkdown)

─ Packages ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 package      * version    date (UTC) lib source
 abind          1.4-5      2016-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 backports      1.4.1      2021-12-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 bayestestR     0.13.0     2022-09-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 bdsmatrix      1.3-6      2022-06-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 bit            4.0.5      2022-11-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 bit64          4.0.5      2020-08-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 bitops         1.0-7      2021-04-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 boot           1.3-28.1   2022-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 broom          1.0.3      2023-01-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 cachem         1.0.6      2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 callr          3.7.3      2022-11-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 car          * 3.1-1      2022-10-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 carData      * 3.0-5      2022-01-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 caTools        1.18.2     2021-03-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 cellranger     1.1.0      2016-07-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 cli            3.6.0      2023-01-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 coda           0.19-4     2020-09-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 collapse       1.9.2      2023-01-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 colorspace     2.1-0      2023-01-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 crayon         1.5.2      2022-09-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 datawizard     0.6.5      2022-12-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 devtools     * 2.4.5      2022-10-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 digest         0.6.31     2022-12-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 dplyr        * 1.1.0      2023-01-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 dreamerr       1.2.3      2020-12-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 dyn          * 0.2-9.6    2018-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 ellipsis       0.3.2      2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 emmeans        1.8.4-1    2023-01-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 estimability   1.4.1      2022-08-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 evaluate       0.20       2023-01-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 fansi          1.0.4      2023-01-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 farver         2.1.1      2022-07-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 fastmap        1.1.0      2021-01-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 fixest       * 0.11.1     2023-01-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 forcats      * 1.0.0      2023-01-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 foreign      * 0.8-83     2022-09-28 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 Formula        1.2-4      2020-10-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 fs             1.6.1      2023-02-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 generics       0.1.3      2022-07-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 ggeffects      1.1.5      2023-01-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 ggplot2      * 3.4.1      2023-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 glue           1.6.2      2022-02-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 gplots       * 3.1.3      2022-04-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 gtable         0.3.1      2022-09-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 gtools         3.9.4      2022-11-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 highr          0.10       2022-12-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 hms            1.1.2      2022-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 htmltools      0.5.4      2022-12-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 htmlwidgets    1.6.1      2023-01-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 httpuv         1.6.9      2023-02-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 httr           1.4.4      2022-08-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 insight        0.19.0     2023-01-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 irr          * 0.84.1     2019-01-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 kableExtra   * 1.3.4      2021-02-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 KernSmooth     2.23-20    2021-05-03 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 knitr          1.42       2023-01-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 labeling       0.4.2      2020-10-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 later          1.3.0      2021-08-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 lattice        0.20-45    2021-09-22 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 lifecycle      1.0.3      2022-10-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 lme4           1.1-31     2022-11-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 lmtest       * 0.9-40     2022-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 lpSolve      * 5.6.18     2023-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 lubridate    * 1.9.2      2023-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 magrittr       2.0.3      2022-03-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 MASS           7.3-58.2   2023-01-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 Matrix         1.5-3      2022-11-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 maxLik         1.5-2      2021-07-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 memoise        2.0.1      2021-11-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 mgcv           1.8-41     2022-10-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 mime           0.12       2021-09-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 miniUI         0.1.1.1    2018-05-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 minqa          1.2.5      2022-10-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 miscTools      0.6-26     2019-12-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 modelr         0.1.10     2022-11-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 munsell        0.5.0      2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 mvtnorm        1.1-3      2021-10-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 nlme           3.1-162    2023-01-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 nloptr         2.0.3      2022-05-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 numDeriv       2016.8-1.1 2019-06-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 pcse         * 1.9.1.1    2018-06-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 performance    0.10.2     2023-01-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 pillar         1.8.1      2022-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 pkgbuild       1.4.0      2022-11-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 pkgconfig      2.0.3      2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 pkgload        1.3.2      2022-11-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 plm          * 2.6-2      2022-08-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 prettyunits    1.1.1      2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 processx       3.8.0      2022-10-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 profvis        0.3.7      2020-11-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 promises       1.2.0.1    2021-02-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 ps             1.7.2      2022-10-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 purrr        * 1.0.1      2023-01-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 R6             2.5.1      2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 ragg           1.2.5      2023-01-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 rbibutils      2.2.13     2023-01-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 Rcpp           1.0.10     2023-01-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 Rdpack         2.4        2022-07-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 readr        * 2.1.4      2023-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 readxl       * 1.4.2      2023-02-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 remotes        2.4.2      2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 rlang          1.0.6      2022-09-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 rmarkdown      2.20       2023-01-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 rstudioapi     0.14       2022-08-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 rvest          1.0.3      2022-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 sandwich     * 3.0-2      2022-06-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 scales         1.2.1      2022-08-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 sessioninfo    1.2.2      2021-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 shiny          1.7.4      2022-12-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 sjlabelled     1.2.0      2022-04-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 sjmisc         2.8.9      2021-12-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 sjPlot       * 2.8.12     2022-11-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 sjstats        0.18.2     2022-11-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 stargazer    * 5.2.3      2022-03-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 stringi        1.7.12     2023-01-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 stringr      * 1.5.0      2022-12-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 svglite        2.1.1      2023-01-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 systemfonts    1.0.4      2022-02-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 texreg       * 1.38.6     2022-04-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 textshaping    0.3.6      2021-10-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 tibble       * 3.1.8      2022-07-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 tidyr        * 1.3.0      2023-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 tidyselect     1.2.0      2022-10-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 tidyverse    * 2.0.0      2023-02-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 timechange     0.2.0      2023-01-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 tzdb           0.3.0      2022-03-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 urlchecker     1.0.1      2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 usethis      * 2.1.6      2022-05-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 utf8           1.2.3      2023-01-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 vctrs          0.5.2      2023-01-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 viridisLite    0.4.1      2022-08-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 vroom          1.6.1      2023-01-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 vtable       * 1.4.1      2022-11-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 webshot        0.5.4      2022-09-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 withr          2.5.0      2022-03-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 xfun           0.37       2023-01-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 xml2           1.3.3      2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 xtable       * 1.8-4      2019-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
 zoo          * 1.8-11     2022-09-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
```

Comment: I do not think `make.unique(<character>) <- "some_character"` will work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line seems flawed:

```
modE<-plm(Total_Net_ODA ~ openness, import, export, index=c("Country.Name", "year"),data = ccomb, model="within")
```

Seems like you want to estimate coefficients for variables `import` and `export`, so you would need to specify them within the `formula` argument, the first argument, like so:

```
modE<-plm(Total_Net_ODA ~ openness + import + export, index=c("Country.Name", "year"),data = ccomb, model="within")
```

Your command inputs `import` and `export` as 2nd and 3rd argument to `plm`, respectively, which is the `data` and `subset` argument.